# Select Distinct está trazendo dados duplicados MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query, distinct

Preciso trazer somente o último cadastro de cada `id_face` que tem na tabela `imagens`, mas por algum motivo está trazendo `id_faces` duplicadas.

Segue minha consulta:

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT(i.id_face) as id_face, 
   i.id_imagens as id_imagens, 
   date_format(i.dt_cad, '%d/%m/%Y \à\s %H:%i') as hora_visita, 
   df.nome, 
   df.email, 
   df.cpf,  
   df.celular, 
   date_format(df.data_nasc, '%d/%m/%Y') as idade, 
   CASE 
      WHEN df.idade_api < 15 THEN '14 ou -' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 15 AND 24 THEN '15 a 24' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN '25 a 34' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 35 AND 44 THEN '35 a 44' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 45 AND 54 THEN '45 a 54' 
      WHEN df.idade_api >= 55 THEN '55 ou +' END as idade_api, 
   CASE 
      WHEN df.genero_api ='f' THEN 'Feminino' ELSE 'Masculino' END as genero, 
   g.nome as grupo_nome, 
   l.nome_loja 
FROM imagens i 
JOIN dados_face df on i.id_face=df.id_face 
JOIN loja l on df.id_loja=l.id_loja 
LEFT JOIN grupo g on g.id_grupo = df.id_grupo 
JOIN iot on iot.id_user='1' WHERE i.dt_cad BETWEEN '2018-09-30 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-04 23:59:59.999999' 
AND df.id_grupo like '%' 
AND l.id_user='1' 
AND i.id_iot in (SELECT id_iot from iot where id_user='1') 
order by i.dt_cad DESC limit 0,24
```

Essa consulta me traz isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que o `id_face` `2355` repete e assim acontece com todos os outros.
Tentei fazer um `group by id_face` mas daí piora muito, pois as datas são exibidas desordenadamente como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me auxiliar na correção desta consulta?
Segue abaixo a estrutura das tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue outra consulta que tentei fazer utilizando `MAX`

```
select 
    distinct(df.id_face),
    MAX(i.id_imagens) as id_imagens, 
    MAX(date_format(i.dt_cad, '%d/%m/%Y \à\s %H:%i')) as hora_visita,
    df.nome,
    df.email,
    df.cpf,                                     
    df.celular,
    date_format(df.data_nasc, '%d/%m/%Y') as idade, 
    CASE WHEN df.idade_api < 15 THEN '14 ou -'
        WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 15 AND 24 THEN '15 a 24'
        WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN '25 a 34'
        WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 35 AND 44 THEN '35 a 44'
        WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 45 AND 54 THEN '45 a 54'
        WHEN df.idade_api >= 55 THEN '55 ou +'
    END as idade_api,                                   
    CASE WHEN df.genero_api ='f' THEN 'Feminino' ELSE 'Masculino' END as genero,
    g.nome as grupo_nome,
    loja.nome_loja
    from dados_face df
    join imagens i on i.id_face=df.id_face  
    LEFT JOIN grupo g on g.id_grupo = df.id_grupo
    JOIN iot on i.id_iot = iot.id_iot   
    JOIN loja on iot.id_loja =  loja.id_loja                                    
    where 
    i.dt_cad BETWEEN '".$data_incial.":00' AND '".$data_final.":59.999999'
    $id_grupo
    AND i.id_iot IN (select id_iot from iot where id_user='".$_SESSION['usuario']['id_user']."')
    AND df.id_loja IN (select id_loja from loja where id_user='".$_SESSION['usuario']['id_user']."')
```

Comment: Não utilizo mysql, mas geralmente o `distinct` ou `group by` vão agrupar as tuplas quando elas são completamente iguais. No caso do id `2355` algumas informações dos dois registros são diferentes como, por exemplo, `id_imagens` e `hora_visita`.

Comment: Acho que vc tinha que usar MAX().

Comment: tentei usar o max e mesmo assim não rolou vou mostrar minha query com o max no post ( vou editar )

Comment: Tentou um subselect com MAX ?

Answer (score 1):

> preciso trazer somente o último cadastro de cada id_face que tem na
> tabela imagens mas por algum motivo está trazendo id_faces duplicadas

Basta acrescentar ao seu `where` uma cláusula que limitará o último registro com base no campo `dt_cad` e `id_face` da tabela `imagens`.
Basta incluir a seguinte restrição no seu `where` :

```
AND i.dt_cad = (Select max(dt_cad) from imagens i2 where i2.id_face = i.id_face)
```

Adaptando sua consulta original, seu comando `SQL` completo ficará:

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT(i.id_face) as id_face, 
   i.id_imagens as id_imagens, 
   date_format(i.dt_cad, '%d/%m/%Y \à\s %H:%i') as hora_visita, 
   df.nome, 
   df.email, 
   df.cpf,  
   df.celular, 
   date_format(df.data_nasc, '%d/%m/%Y') as idade, 
   CASE 
      WHEN df.idade_api < 15 THEN '14 ou -' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 15 AND 24 THEN '15 a 24' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN '25 a 34' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 35 AND 44 THEN '35 a 44' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 45 AND 54 THEN '45 a 54' 
      WHEN df.idade_api >= 55 THEN '55 ou +' END as idade_api, 
   CASE 
      WHEN df.genero_api ='f' THEN 'Feminino' ELSE 'Masculino' END as genero, 
   g.nome as grupo_nome, 
   l.nome_loja 
FROM imagens i 
JOIN dados_face df on i.id_face=df.id_face 
JOIN loja l on df.id_loja=l.id_loja 
LEFT JOIN grupo g on g.id_grupo = df.id_grupo 
JOIN iot on iot.id_user='1' WHERE i.dt_cad BETWEEN '2018-09-30 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-04 23:59:59.999999' 
AND df.id_grupo like '%' 
AND l.id_user='1' 
AND i.id_iot in (SELECT id_iot from iot where id_user='1') 
AND i.dt_cad = (Select max(dt_cad) from imagens i2 where i2.id_face = i.id_face)  
order by i.dt_cad DESC limit 0,24
```

Desta forma, para cada registro da coleção, o resultado estará limitado à máxima `dt_cad` (data de cadastro) para cada `id_face` da tabela `imagens`.

Provavelmente, seja desnecessário o uso do `LEFT JOIN grupo g on g.id_grupo = df.id_grupo` , verifique a possibilidade de trocá-lo apenas por `Join` e desta forma poderá também retirar o `DISTINCT(i.id_face)` da sua consulta original.

### Sobre o uso do DISTINCT

O `DISTINCT` na consulta original da pergunta não fez efeito, pois esse comando depende de todos os campos exibidos na seleção e não apenas daquele colocado entre parênteses, desta forma, para retirar linhas duplicadas, seria necessário que o conteúdo de todos os campos possuíssem os mesmos valores.
Por exemplo, considere uma tabela chamada `tabela_exemplo` seguinte:

| campo1 | campo2 | campo3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

Ao executar a consulta:

```
Select distinct(campo1), campo2, campo3 from tabela_exemplo  order by campo1;
```

Será equivalente a utilizar a consulta:

```
Select distinct * from tabela_exemplo order by campo1;
```

Cujo resultado em ambas será:

| campo1 | campo2 | campo3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

Agora, se considerar na seleção apenas os dois primeiros campos, como no comando seguinte:

```
select distinct(campo1), campo2 from tabela_exemplo order by campo1;
```

O resultado seria:

| campo1 | campo2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

Desta forma, fica também esclarecido o motivo do `DISTINCT` não ter,  aparentemente, funcionado. Os valores a serem exibidos nos campo precisam ser iguais para que exista a supressão de uma das linhas.

Answer (score 0):

O distinct não irá trazer uma linha por id, pra tal você precisará definir quais linhas daquele id você irá trazer e filtrar no where para vir apenas uma linha, ou, fazer um cursor. Por exemplo, se você deseja apenas uma linha por id com a linha com a última data de visita, pode usar um inner join novamente com a tabela images (i1 e i2) , onde i1.id = i2.id and i1.dt_cad = max(i2.dt_cad), assim ele buscará apenas a linha de maior data de último acesso.

Comment: Edson obrigado pela resposta. Eu meio que entendi o que você quis dizer mas pode me dar um ex do inner join? não consegui fazer aqui. Agradeço

Answer (score 0):

E se fizer assim:

```
SELECT 
   **i.id_face,** 
   i.id_imagens as id_imagens, 
   date_format(i.dt_cad, '%d/%m/%Y \à\s %H:%i') as hora_visita, 
   df.nome, 
   df.email, 
   df.cpf,  
   df.celular, 
   date_format(df.data_nasc, '%d/%m/%Y') as idade, 
   CASE 
      WHEN df.idade_api < 15 THEN '14 ou -' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 15 AND 24 THEN '15 a 24' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN '25 a 34' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 35 AND 44 THEN '35 a 44' 
      WHEN df.idade_api BETWEEN 45 AND 54 THEN '45 a 54' 
      WHEN df.idade_api >= 55 THEN '55 ou +' END as idade_api, 
   CASE 
      WHEN df.genero_api ='f' THEN 'Feminino' ELSE 'Masculino' END as genero, 
   g.nome as grupo_nome, 
   l.nome_loja 
FROM imagens i 
JOIN dados_face df on i.id_face=df.id_face 
JOIN loja l on df.id_loja=l.id_loja 
LEFT JOIN grupo g on g.id_grupo = df.id_grupo 
JOIN iot on iot.id_user='1' WHERE i.dt_cad BETWEEN '2018-09-30 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-04 23:59:59.999999' 
AND df.id_grupo like '%' 
AND l.id_user='1' 
AND i.id_iot in (SELECT id_iot from iot where id_user='1') 
**GROUP BY 
   i.id_face, 
   i.id_imagens, 
   date_format(i.dt_cad, '%d/%m/%Y \à\s %H:%i'), 
   df.nome, 
   df.email, 
   df.cpf,  
   df.celular, 
   date_format(df.data_nasc, '%d/%m/%Y'),    
   l.nome_loja** 
order by i.dt_cad DESC limit 0,24
```

Comment: ainda repete: https://prnt.sc/lqki5c